# How to properly align the fields of SHELLSTATE struct?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

Someone could help me to write the proper definition (in C# or VB.NET) for the **[SHELLSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** structure?.

My own definition is not working properly, some members don't work as expected, for example `fShowAllObjects` works fine, but `fShowExtensions` doesn't, I can't set the field to `True`, so I think is because the field packing is wrong.

I'm not sure whether I should specify a `StructLayoutAttribute.Pack` attribute, or I need to specify the `LayoutKind.Explicit` then specify the proper field offset for each field, or marshal the `Boolean` fields to 1-byte with `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)>`, those are things that I tried without success, I need help to do it right.

C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ShellState
{
    public bool ShowAllObjects;
    public bool ShowExtensions;
    public bool NoConfirmRecycle;
    public bool ShowSysFiles;
    public bool ShowCompColor;
    public bool DoubleClickInWebView;
    public bool DesktopHtml;
    public bool Win95Classic;
    public bool DontPrettyPath;
    public bool Unused1;
    public bool MapNetDrvBtn;
    public bool ShowInfoTip;
    public bool HideIcons;
    public bool WebView;
    public bool Unused2;
    public bool ShowSuperHidden;
    public bool NoNetCrawling;
    public int Unused3;
    public uint Unused4;
    public long ParamSort;
    public int SortDirection;
    public uint Unused5;
    public uint Unused6;
    public bool SepProcess;
    public bool WinXpStartPanelOn;
    public bool Unused7;
    public bool AutoCheckSelect;
    public bool IconsOnly;
    public bool ShowTypeOverlay;
    public bool ShowStatusBar;
    public uint Unused8;
}
```

VB.NET:

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure ShellState
    Public ShowAllObjects As Boolean
    Public ShowExtensions As Boolean
    Public NoConfirmRecycle As Boolean
    Public ShowSysFiles As Boolean
    Public ShowCompColor As Boolean
    Public DoubleClickInWebView As Boolean
    Public DesktopHtml As Boolean
    Public Win95Classic As Boolean
    Public DontPrettyPath As Boolean
    Public Unused1 As Boolean
    Public MapNetDrvBtn As Boolean
    Public ShowInfoTip As Boolean
    Public HideIcons As Boolean
    Public WebView As Boolean
    Public Unused2 As Boolean
    Public ShowSuperHidden As Boolean
    Public NoNetCrawling As Boolean
    Public Unused3 As Integer
    Public Unused4 As UInteger
    Public ParamSort As Long
    Public SortDirection As Integer
    Public Unused5 As UInteger
    Public Unused6 As UInteger
    Public SepProcess As Boolean
    Public WinXpStartPanelOn As Boolean
    Public Unused7 As Boolean
    Public AutoCheckSelect As Boolean
    Public IconsOnly As Boolean
    Public ShowTypeOverlay As Boolean
    Public ShowStatusBar As Boolean
    Public Unused8 As UInteger
End Structure
```

---

I'll also supply the **[SHGetSetSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762200%28VS.85%29.aspx)** function for further testing of the resulting structure modifications:

```vb
<DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError:=False)>
Public Shared Sub SHGetSetSettings(<[In]> <Out> ByRef refState As ShellState,
                  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal mask As ShellStateFlags,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal applyState As Boolean)
End Sub
```

And the **[SSF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** Enumeration:

```vb
<Flags>
Public Enum ShellStateFlags As UInteger
    ShowAllObjects = &H1
    ShowFilenameExtensions = &H2
    ShowCompressedColor = &H8
    SortColumns = &H10
    ShowSystemFiles = &H20
    DoubleClickInWebView = &H80
    DesktopHtml = &H200
    Win95Classic = &H400
    DontPrettyPath = &H800
    MapNetDrvBtn = &H1000
    ShowInfoTip = &H2000
    HideIcons = &H4000
    NoConfirmRecycle = &H8000
    WebView = &H20000
    ShowSuperHiddenFiles = &H40000
    ExplorerSeparateProcess = &H80000
    NoNetCrawling = &H100000
    AutoChecboxkSelection = &H800000
    ShowIconsOnly = &H1000000
    ShowTypeOverlay = &H2000000
    ShowStatusBar = &H4000000
End Enum
```

Comment: I think your problem is that those booleans are bitfields. Looks like you have to implement some wrapper properties that twiddle the bits of the underlying field. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6720d6ba-fde6-4c75-ae06-79e69f1e7d87/bit-fields-in-cnet?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Whaaa! It will be harder than what I imagined at first sight. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @David Heffernan If I remember good was you who explained me a lot of things about field offsets (and unions) because other annonying and really bigger struct, you also explained me how to determine the field size with VC++ (or maybe I did that thing by my own, I don't remember) but I can't find the question with your comments (so pathetic me, my owns questions...I even don't remember the struct name), if you read this and if you remember that question, please mention the url!, ensure you that I appreciate your words about "Try it first in C++ to compare offsets".

Comment: Hmm that's nasty. All those bit fields. Don't forget also that c++ long is 32 bit. C# long is 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one ugly struct. From experimentation I determined that the fields are 4 byte aligned, and that the overall struct size (MSVC compiler) is 32 bytes. Given that, the following structure should work. (Notes after)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SHELLSTATE // int (4 byte) alignment
{
    public uint firstFlags; // includes alignment padding
    public uint dwWin95Unused;
    public uint uWin95Unused;
    public int lParamSort;
    public int iSortDirection;
    public uint version;
    public uint uNotUsed;
    public uint secondFlags; // includes spares at end to prevent access violation

    public bool fShowAllObjects => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000001) == 0x00000001;
    public bool fShowExtensions => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000002) == 0x00000002;
    public bool fNoConfirmRecycle => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000004) == 0x00000004;
    public bool fShowSysFiles => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000008) == 0x00000008;
    public bool fShowCompColor => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000010) == 0x00000010;
    public bool fDoubleClickInWebView => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000020) == 0x00000020;
    public bool fDesktopHTML => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000040) == 0x00000040;
    public bool fWin95Classic => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000080) == 0x00000080;
    public bool fDontPrettyPath => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000100) == 0x00000100;
    public bool fShowAttribCol => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000200) == 0x00000200;
    public bool fMapNetDrvBtn => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000400) == 0x00000400;
    public bool fShowInfoTip => (this.firstFlags & 0x00000800) == 0x00000800;
    public bool fHideIcons => (this.firstFlags & 0x00001000) == 0x00001000;
    public bool fWebView => (this.firstFlags & 0x00002000) == 0x00002000;
    public bool fFilter => (this.firstFlags & 0x00004000) == 0x00004000;
    public bool fShowSuperHidden => (this.firstFlags & 0x00008000) == 0x00008000;
    public bool fNoNetCrawling => (this.firstFlags & 0x00010000) == 0x00010000;
    public bool fSepProcess => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000001) == 0x00000001;
    public bool fStartPanelOn => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000002) == 0x00000002;
    public bool fShowStartPage => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000004) == 0x00000004;
    public bool fAutoCheckSelect => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000008) == 0x00000008;
    public bool fIconsOnly => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000010) == 0x00000010;
    public bool fShowTypeOverlay => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000020) == 0x00000020;
    public bool fShowStatusBar => (this.secondFlags & 0x00000040) == 0x00000040;

    public override string ToString() => $"SHELLSTATE Version: {this.version}";
}
```

Since I wrote the original answer, I rechecked that the flags were correctly broken out, using some C++/CLI:

```
static IntPtr GetShellState()
{
    SHELLSTATE* state = (SHELLSTATE*)calloc(1, sizeof(SHELLSTATE));
    state->fShowAllObjects = TRUE;
    return IntPtr((void*)state);
}

static String^ SetNext(IntPtr value, int% flags)
{
    String^ result;

    SHELLSTATE* state = (SHELLSTATE*)value.ToPointer();
    if (state->fShowAllObjects)
    {
        state->fShowAllObjects = FALSE;
        state->fShowExtensions = TRUE;
        result = gcnew String("fShowExtensions");
        flags = 0;
    }
    else if (state->fShowExtensions)
    {
        // Removed other flag toggling
    return result;
}

static void FreeShellState(IntPtr value)
{
    if (value != IntPtr::Zero)
    {
        void* ptr = value.ToPointer();
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

And then generated the flags using the following C#:

```
IntPtr s = Class1.GetShellState();
string itemName = "fShowAllObjects";
int flags = 0;

Func<IntPtr, int, uint> ReadFlags = (IntPtr ptr, int item) => (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, item == 0 ? 0 : 28);

uint val = ReadFlags(s, flags);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"public bool {itemName} => (this.{(flags == 0 ? "first" : "second")}Flags & 0x{val.ToString("X8")}) == 0x{val.ToString("X8")};");

while (flags < 2)
{
    itemName = Class1.SetNext(s, ref flags);
    val = ReadFlags(s, flags);
    Debug.Print($"public bool {itemName} => (this.{(flags == 0 ? "first" : "second")}Flags & 0x{val.ToString("X8")}) == 0x{val.ToString("X8")};");
}

Class1.FreeShellState(s);
```

To test it I used a `SHGetSetSettings` P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
public static extern void SHGetSetSettings(ref SHELLSTATE lpss, 
                                           UInt32 dwMask, 
                                           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bSet);
```

and called the function:

```
SHELLSTATE state = new SHELLSTATE();
SHGetSetSettings(ref state, 0xFFFFFFFF, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. These are fields that are working: `fShowAllObjects, fShowExtensions, fShowCompColor, fShowInfoTip, fHideIcons, fShowSuperHidden,fSepProcess, fAutoCheckSelect, fIconsOnly, fShowStatusBar`. These are fields that are not working: `fNoConfirmRecycle, fShowSysFiles, fNoNetCrawling, fShowTypeOverlay`, (they have always the same value) the rest of fields I didn't tested them because I'm not interested to they.

Comment: I really would like to learn how to inspect to know how to do the necessary modifications of what you've did to build the proper definition of that struct, but I don't know, so I'll ask you: Could you please try to fix the structure to make `fNoConfirmRecycle` and `fShowSysFiles` (at least those) work?, I tried with different offset values without success, Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - It didn't really end up needing the explicit layout in the end, but I left it there to make it clear where each member actually is since the question is about the layout of the struct. (Yep, could have made each of those a comment, but didn't. And yes, I know `LayoutKind.Sequential` would work just fine.)

Comment: @ElektroStudios - I'll take a look at those flags. Also if you want to include a VB answer, please feel free to post it as a separate answer, rather than editing it into mine.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I can confirm that the flags are broken out correctly.  See the updated post. I have no idea why the values for `fConfirmRecycle` and `fShowSysFiles` aren't showing up correct for you, but they seem to work correctly for me.

Comment: @theB The next question is weird but my English is not perfect, please could you express with other friendlly words what you mean with "broken out correctlly"?, "broken" and "correctlly" seems contradictory, but I imagine you mean it works for you.

Comment: The "fNoConfirmRecycle" behavior is very strange in Windows 10, seems that a trick of a related registry value was overriding the change by SHGetSetSettings,I deleted the value and then It worked, wel, viewing the recycle bin properties window I ensured that SHGetSetSettings changes the value, but really it don't works because a confirmation dialog is always shown, but the function changes the value so I'll don't worry more about.

Comment: I tested the fields in a Virtual Machine and all is working ok, except "fShowSystemFiles", in a fresh installation of Windows 10 the value returned in the SHELLSTATE is always "True" for that field, even if I disabled the "show system files" feature in explorer's settings, then, if the value on SHELLSTATE is always "True", doesn't that mean the field is wrong declared in the source code?.

Comment: In a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 x64 happens the same problem with "fShowSystemFiles", always is "True", so protected files are not showing or hidding respectivelly.

Comment: To [break out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20out): To make ready for action or to use. In this case it means that the values of the flags are separated for use.  I can confirm that the positions of those flags bits are correct, from the C++/CLI code I wrote that sets the flags directly, and passes the raw structure to the managed C# code.

Comment: Also, `fShowSysFiles` doesn't correspond to the "Hide protected operating system files" setting in the folder view options. That particular option in the dialog corresponds to the `fShowSuperHidden` flag, (super hidden files being those with both the hidden and system attributes) The `fShowSysFiles` flag maps to the "Show hidden files, folders and drives" option. (The radio buttons under "Hidden Files and Folders")